# WebScraping issue output is "none"

Tags: python, web-scraping

input:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def FBPrice():
    r = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB?p=FB')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'xml')
    price = soup.find('div', class_ = 'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)')
    return price 

while True:
    print("The current price is:" +str(FBPrice()))
```

output:
The current price is:None

I do not know why I am getting "none" as a response. I'm trying to get the current price of FB's stock off of yahoo.

Comment: It didn't find what you were looking for. with `soup.find...`  Did you try searching for other things you knew were in the data?   I don't know what you get if you just type `print (r)` or `print(soup)` to ensure you are getting returns you think you should get.

Comment: Yes, I am getting the correct website and when and the correct html source code when I type print(r) I get the website status code and when I print(soup) I get the source code like I'm supposed to, I do not know what is wrong.

Comment: I don't see the price when i do a print(soup) ? probably selenium is you best bet. but please use a some time in between in your while as otherwise you are going to be blocked.

Comment: Also https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/ might be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know your problem but i guess your problem is wrong class element, you just should find Id element

i highly recommend you using Selenium and Scapy,Selenium support XPATH, auto remove some element, auto click... , easy than use requests library

selenium docs: Here's [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html)

scapy: Here's [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/)

Answer (score 0):

There were some mistakes in your code I have fixed it you check it below.

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def FBPrice():
    r = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB?p=FB')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    price = soup.find('span', {"data-reactid":"32"})
    return price.text

while True:
    print("The current price is:" +str(FBPrice()))
```

Output:
[image: output]

Let me know if you have any questions :)